# #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit in vscode when trying to code with C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
[#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit][1] (C:\Users\kw27w\OneDrive\Desktop\test\test.c).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "stdbool.h"C/C++(1696)
```

That's the error that occured and there is a red line under <stdio.h> and a lightbulb when I click on it it says `edit "includepath" settings` and when I click it moves over to "c_cpp_properties.json".

How and where can I add include paths in the configurations below?

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Users\\kw27w\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.3.0"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My code was

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. The first few prime numbers are {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ….}

The idea to solve this problem is to iterate through all the numbers starting from 2 to sqrt(N) using a for loop and for every number check if it divides N. If we find any number that divides, we return false. If we did not find any number between 2 and sqrt(N) which divides N then it means that N is prime and we will return True. 
Why did we choose sqrt(N)? 
The reason is that the smallest and greater than one factor of a number cannot be more than the sqrt of N. And we stop as soon as we find a factor. For example, if N is 49, the smallest factor is 7. For 15, smallest factor is 3.
*/

bool is_prime(int n){
  int i, flag = 1;
    // Iterate from 2 to sqrt(n)
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
 
        // If n is divisible by any number between
        // 2 and n/2, it is not prime
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
 
    if (n <= 1)
        flag = 0;
 
    if (flag == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: the errors picture]

Comment: For c++ code, there is no need for include `stdbool.h`

Comment: it's acually c code not c++

Comment: Then don't tag it with `c++`

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are on Mac? I just ran into the same issue.

Do you have homebrew installed? If not, then that is your issue. Mac OS are missing a lot of stuff that Windows OS normally has [per HomeBrew homepage, "Homebrew, The Missing Package Manager for macOS (or Linux)"].
So we need to download everything missing onto our Mac OS, and HomeBrew is the solution for that:  https://brew.sh << download is here.

If for some reason you cannot install HomeBrew, then Microsoft has a solution here:
https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html

let me know how it works out.